# Why are induced field lines circular?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential

Whenever we have a changing magnetic flux through a conductor an induced electric field is generated. It is often said that these induced electric field lines are circular in shape.But why is this so?Why are these field lines not elliptical for example?
How can this shape be mathematically derived?

Also does this have anything to do with equipotential surfaces?Do such non-conservative electric fields even produce a potential field?If not why?

Comment: They can be elliptical.  The shape of the induced electric field depends on the shape of the  changing magnetic field.

Comment: How can this shape be mathematically derived?

Comment: What can be done to attract answers

Comment: "How can this shape be mathematically derived?"  It is pretty straightforward if you know vector calculus.  Just use Maxwell's equations to describe a changing current density, and solve for the induced electric field.

Comment: I don't know vector calculus

Comment: Can u still post the derivation?..I haven't been able to find it any textbook

Comment: I will wrap my comments together to form an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The induced fields can be many shapes other than circular, such as elliptical.  It can easily be shown using Maxwell's equations that unless the changing current density is axially symmetric, the induced electric field lines will not be circular.

If you don't know calculus, you won't understand the derivation. But think about it this way: A uniform bundle of straight magnetic field lines (e.g., formed by an infinitely long solenoid coil) that is steadily increasing in strength will indeed generate a circular electric field around the bundle, because the bundle and fields will be axially symmetric. But two such bundles, separated by some distance, will each produce their own circular field. When the two fields are added together (as vectors), the sum field will not be circular because there will not be axial symmetry (due to the two separated bundles of magnetic field lines).

Comment: Can u still post the mathematical derivation anyway?I basic differential and integral calculus and understand vector calculus somewhat

Comment: No, I won't post the derivation but I'm willing to guide you to derive it yourself.  We may need to do it in Chat.  But first step: can you derive the magnetic field around a wire carrying a constant current?

Comment: Yes,it's UI(sin(alpha)+sin(beta))/4πz

Comment: You need to define your terms.

Comment: Sure, I - current..alpha ,beta are angles From the point where the field is to be found to the end of the wire,..z is perpendicular distance from point to wire....U is permeability of vacuum

Comment: A suggestion:  Please think this through, calculate the fields, and edit your original question to include your calculations.  There is a good possibility that you will find the answer to the question in the process of doing this.

Comment: Calculate field of what?

Comment: I already know the field of a current carrying wire...and the second part of my question is also unanswered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100326/discussion-between-s-mcgrew-and-schwarz-kugelblitz).