# Are induced electric field lines circular in nature?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I know that induced electric field lines form closed loops but we always see that in textbooks, induced electric field lines are drawn circular loops. So my question is that are induced electric field lines always circular in nature or can they be of any shape, and I also want to know why everyone draws these lines as circular?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are induced field lines circular?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509026/why-are-induced-field-lines-circular)

Comment: So can you just give me examples that how other shapes of field can be formed?

Comment: Can you solve these questions in the above pictures ??

Comment: That is clearly stated in the linked question's answers. Please have a look.

Comment: Sir but still I am unable to understand probably because I unable to understand the English??

Comment: But can you tell me the answer of the question in above image